# Add in ASCII values to Java Affine Cipher

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

Im learning to create a java programme to encrypt and decrypt messages using Affine Cipher by following [this tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/implementation-affine-cipher/)

What im trying to understand is how to add in characters from 'a-z' and other characters like fullstops and commas and spaces to my programme.

What is the reason behind adding 'A' before encrypting?

```
static String encryptMessage(char[] msg)
{
    /// Cipher Text initially empty
    String cipher = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < msg.length; i++)
    {
        // Avoid space to be encrypted
        /* applying encryption formula ( a x + b ) mod m
        {here x is msg[i] and m is 26} and added 'A' to
        bring it in range of ascii alphabet[ 65-90 | A-Z ] */
        if (msg[i] != ' ')
        {
            cipher = cipher
                    + (char) ((((a * (msg[i] - 'A')) + b) % 26) + 'A');
        } else // else simply append space character
        {
            cipher += msg[i];
        }
    }
    return cipher;
}
```

I understand its got something to do with ASCII values but not sure what the reason is.

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define an alphabet string, and use the index of the characters in that alphabet instead of relying on the order of characters in ASCII. You can use `String#indexOf` to find the index of the characters in the string.

I recommend creating separate functions that maps a character to an index and back again to ease development and debugging. The remainder operation should of course be over the length of the alphabet string, instead of 26. I'd also recommend to use a message as `String` and of course to use a `StringBuilder` to create the ciphertext.

Comment: thanks, was able to follow what you suggested and make it work!